# How to use Look delta values for 2d rotation?

Tags: unity, c#

I have InputActions that are pretty much the defaults. Specifically, a Look action that uses the pointer delta (action type Value, control type Vector 2).

How can I translate this information into a look angle that I can apply to a gameObject's rotation? I know the traditional way of making an object rotate to look at the mouse is using LookAt and functions like that, but I don't want to use that because (a) I want the looking to be independent of the mouse's distance from the game object and (b) I want to use the Look action since it'll allow the exact same code to be used regardless of whether the player is using a mouse or a joystick on a gamepad (I think).

For example, if I move my mouse in a north-east direction, how can I pull that angle ('north east', i.e. 45 degrees if 0 degrees is north) from the delta values I'm getting?

Comment: Usually you'd use different logic for a mouse pointer than a joystick. For a joystick, what matters is where the stick is pushed within its dome of travel. For a mouse, what matters is where the mouse cursor is on-screen *relative to the character*. I don't think delta values you get natively from the input system are going to be sufficient for your needs, unless you want a cursor below your character to make them look up if it moves up 2 pixels, while staying below the character on screen.

Comment: I'm mostly trying to make a character rotation controller that's independent of mouse distance from the character, is the goal.

Comment: Sounds to me like you just need good ol' [atan2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/69676/39518). Can you show how you've tried using existing answers about [turning a mouse offset into a facing direction](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=mouse+angle) to solve this problem, and where you've run into a new issue we can help you with?